# Imagem não é carregada como background

Tags: html, css, html5, codeigniter

Olá, tenho o seguinte código como parte do meu index.php

```
<style>
  #backgroundImage{
    background-image: url('<?=base_url();?>bg.jpg');
  }
</style>
<body id='backgroundImage'>
</body>
```

Porém a imagem não está sendo carregada. Tenho uma imagem padrão chamada fundo.jpg essa carrega, mas se eu alterar o nome da imagem ela não carrega. Ambas as imagens encontram-se no caminho correto.

Comment: Existe uma imagem bg.jpg, porém ela não é renderizada

Answer (score 0):

No caminho da imagem, não precisa das aspas. Nesse caso também não, mas tem que concatenar com o nome da imagem.

```
<style>
  #backgroundImage{
     background-image: url(<?=base_url().'bg.jpg'?>);
  }
</style>

<body id='backgroundImage'></body>
```

Answer (score -1):

A parte em CSS não está escrita corretamente, o style em geral é melhor referenciar por class e não id, como se faz em Javascript. E ainda, existe uma forma melhor de localizar a imagem usando função do Codeigniter. Considerando que `bg.jpg` está na raiz do seu site, faça o seguinte na sua view:

```
<html>
    <header>
        <style>
            body { background-image: url("<?=base_url('bg.jpg')?>"); }
        </style>
    </header>
    <body>
        <!-- a imagem estará aqui -->
    </body>
</html>
```